# How to install RDP Client Access License trial or use its grace period?

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp, licensing

We want to have multiple active sessions in Windows Server 2012. Each active session will run an app to which one user will be connected. The problem is that we can not keep more than 2 sessions active at a time.

As explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/631819/how-can-i-enable-multiple-users-login-at-a-time-in-remote-system) we probably need to have RDP CALs for each session. But before buying we want to try how well it works in our scenario.

So how do I install the trial license in Windows Server 2012 for RDP to have multiple active sessions? Or what setup/configuration do I need if there is no trial license/grace period needed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: @Massimo What is the right place to ask this particular question then? I couldn't find it elsewhere. This is about a feature that I seem to unable to use because of license. I explained the problem in case if it was not a license issue at all.

Comment: You are correct, I retracted my close vote. However, you should edit your question to clarify that you are not actually looking for a trial license, but for how to install a RDP server and use its grace period.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CALs are not what is limiting you to 2 sessions.  You need to go through the Remote Desktop Services installation process through Server Manager.

Here is an article from Microsoft about the process:

[Remote Desktop Services (RDS) Quick Start Deployment for RemoteApp, Windows Server 2012 Style](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yungchou/2013/02/07/remote-desktop-services-rds-quick-start-deployment-for-remoteapp-windows-server-2012-style/)

After you go through the process there is a 120 day grace period before you need to install licensing.

Comment: I had to setup the server as domain first than it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

After you install the RDP roles, you should be able to use unlimited CALs for the grace period:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh553157(v=ws.10).aspx

120 days I believe.

The Grace period starts from when the RDP server receives its first connection.